# How to create a file for configuring the ConnectionString in a Analysis Services Project?

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, connection-string

In the Analysis Services Project, I have set the ConnectionString in olap.ds and it works well.

However everytime I change the password of the database, I will need to deploy the project again as I can only config it in the olap.ds file.

Is there any way that I can setup a config file to manage the ConnectionString? So I just need to modify the config file instead of re-deploying the project.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XMLA script. The following is an example for AdwentureWorks Cube. You can run such script from SSMS or from PowerShell.

```
<Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
<Object>
    <DatabaseID>AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE</DatabaseID>
    <DataSourceID>Adventure Works DW</DataSourceID>
</Object>
<ObjectDefinition>
    <DataSource xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xsi:type="RelationalDataSource">
        <ID>Adventure Works DW</ID>
        <Name>AdventureWorksDW2012</Name>
        <ConnectionString>Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW2012</ConnectionString>
        <ImpersonationInfo>
            <ImpersonationMode>ImpersonateAccount</ImpersonationMode>
                <Account>domain\login</Account>
                <Password>password</Password>
        </ImpersonationInfo>
        <Timeout>PT0S</Timeout>
    </DataSource>
</ObjectDefinition>
```

Please note that you have to use windows domain accounts for data access, or store your login and password in connection string in plain text.

Comment: Sorry I have one more question, I find that there is a "named ConnectionString" in the connection manager. Is that another way to use Configuration file to set the ConnectionString?

Comment: What do you mean by "named connection string"? Tag <Name> before <ConnectionString> defines the name of data source for specified connection string, normally you should not change it but have to specify it.

Comment: In Data Source Designer > Edit > Connection Manager

Comment: You showed one of various Connection String properties. If you need yo set it, do and check how it modifies the Connection String. This is a non-default and optional property, in general you do not have specify it.
You could see samples of Connection String at https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/